# In Site.com, can I access URL variables inside of {!} brackets

Tags: site.com, data

I can access fields from an Object inside a Data Repeater, with code like `{!account__r.Account_name}` etc. How can I access a URL parameter this way, as I can in Visual Force with `{!($CurrentPage.parameters.z)}`?

I imagine it's likely this functionality doesn't exist yet (much like my other questions in [site.com](/questions/tagged/site.com)), but perhaps someone has done it.

Yes, I can get it with javascript, but that doesn't help at page load-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualforce global functions don't work in Site.com. All you have to do is with JavaScript. There are little bit different functions available in Site.com itself which can be seen when using data repeater or other dynamic component. It gives some global available functions like parameter, record id , current user etc.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. All I can see in the data repeater is that I can use fields that are in the object to which I'm connecting. Are there other functions or parameters I can access?